# how to send request get method in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

How to send request to get method in play? i have play framework application, and java desktop application. I want to send a request from java desktop to play framework with method get.

**Here's routes file play framework**

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                 Application.index
POST    /auth                             Application.authenticator
POST    /datacompany                      Application.getDataCompany
POST    /listdatafile                     Application.getListFile
POST    /urlfile                          Application.getUrlFile
GET     /getFile/{id}                     Application.getFile
# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                         staticDir:public

# Catch all                 
*/{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

**Here's method in Application controller play**

```
  public static void getFile(String id){
   //String id = params.get("id");
        System.out.println("ID : "+id);
        FileInputStream stream = ResumableDownloader.getFile(id);
        renderBinary(stream);
    }
```

oh and i for now i just want to send request to `GET     /getFile/{id}                        Application.getFile`

Thank's and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a HTTP client in your java desktop application.  Check out HttpClient: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: i had tried that method, when i using that method, classNotFoundException error is showing for org.apache.commons.logging. I try to add library common-logging-1.1.3.jar to my project, but it doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like you need to sort out project classpath